# DJANGO: Sort dictionary by value (and sent to a template)

Tags: django, sorting, dictionary

I've run into the following problem: for my webapp I'm creating a page that shows how many reviews the top 10 posters users have posted on my website.

(In the format `Username - Number_of_reviews`)

The information is passed to the template as a dictionary, that is generated by the following function in view.py:

def hall_of_game(request):

```
(....)

review_histogram = {}
most_reviews = {}
for x in Vote.objects.all():
    review_histogram[x.voter] = review_histogram.get(x.voter, 0) + 1
sorted_list = []
for key, value in review_histogram.items():
    sorted_list.append((value, key))
    sorted_list.sort(reverse=True)
return render(request, 'list/hall_of_fame.html', {(....), 'sorted': sorted_list})
```

The template then turns the dictionary into a ordered list

```
<ol>
 {% for v, k in sorted|slice:":10" %}
 <li>{{ k }} - {{ v }}</li>
 {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

However, the moment 2 or more users have the same amount of reviews the function can no longer sort the list and it crashes, throwing a type error.

TypeError
  unorderable types: User() < User()

I tried fixing the problem by putting the moment the list is sorted in a 'try / except' loop, and though this prevents crashes this also prevents the list from being sorted.

I feel like I'm ignoring the obvious but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the sort call a key function to tell it to sort by the first element of the tuple only:

```
for key, value in review_histogram.items():
    sorted_list.append((value, key))
sorted_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
```

Also note the call should be outside the loop, otherwise you're sorting unnecessarily on each iteration.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. I've also pulled the .sort() call outside of the loop, thanks for the quick response!